# Deep Learning : producing one image out of a video

Tags: deep-learning

I am asking myself either it would be possible to train a neural network to create one image out of a video.

My question is not to select one image inside the video, but to create one image out of the blue, image which would make someone think about the video's content.

For example : a video about cars would generate an image of a car for example.

As a training set we can think of all the videos on youtube : you have the video, and for each one there is a selected front-image which represent the video.

So we do have a training set, the question is now how do we make a neural network generating the image from a video ? It make me think of deep dream...

Comment: *For example a video about cars would generate an image of a car.*  So, let's see.  You have to train the neural network to recognize a car, compare all the images of a car in the video, and produce one image of a car that what?  Combines the attributes of all the cars? Picks out the most displayed car?  And that's just one type of video.

Comment: So, would you use the thumbnails as targets? Would that work as a supervised learning task with a GAN? There are pretrained networks out there that perform image synopsis, I am not aware of video applications. There may be video to text synopsis thats relevant as well.

Comment: This question will have more success, audience on https://ai.stackexchange.com/ don't you think ?

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc you got it "that's just one type of video" => for me the question is the generalisation => could you make a DL network, understand what would be a good thumbnail for a video (and creating the thmbnail, not picking it up from the video itself!)

Comment: @GaussianPrior : yes, the thumbnails are the target => my question is : can a DL model create a thumbnail from a video (but a thumbnail which wouldn't be a selected image from the video, just a new one created by the network, which would make the user think about the video's content)

Comment: @Soleil-MathieuPrévot : I didn't know this site, thanks !

Comment: As far as YouTube video thumbnails, have you not heard the term, "click-bait"?  Thumbnail images created by people can be deliberately misleading.  I suppose an AI can be taught to produce images from video.  The question is, how can you teach an AI that much context in that it can pick out objects, know what those objects are, and then produce an image where a person would say, "yep, that image represents the video."  Seems to me that the AI would have to understand an awful lot of contextual objects.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc I never heard of click-bait, interesting. But yes, the idea is exactly what you describe : ability for an AI to select what is meaningful inside a video... Let's begin with short videos with not a lot of object in it ;)

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc There is **no understanding** to date in AI, nor not any awareness or ego. This is a marketing thing to sell a brand. An AI today is a function without any creativity or *libre-arbitre*, designed by the engineer, partly by the code/architecture, partly by the data and the definition of groundtruth that was/is provided.

Comment: @RomainJouin There are research papers in computer vision on "abstracting" a video; your idea of a one-image synthesis can be a step futher from that research. But absolutely no DL is required, and that would be easier in term of engineering to implement and tune. However, there is no image synthesis, that would be a GAN's job, and that could be the step following the abstract production. However there is no "meaning" involved in there.